# Android programming: ANDROID_CONTEXT parameter is not passed in error

Tags: java, android, speech

I'm programming an app with that Nuance SpeechKit that performs TTS. It requires the context (called from `getApplicationContext()`) to be passed into some functions. Unfortunately, I'm getting this error in my log: `ANDROID_CONTEXT parameter is not passed in!!!`

Let me give more background: There in a main activity, and it opens a dialog from a button. The dialog invokes the text-to-speech functionality. As a result, I call `getApplicationContext()` in the main activity and pass it to my `DialogFragment` as a parameter using setters. Unfortunately, I'm getting this error even though I am calling the setters. So what could be going wrong? Here's a bit of code:

In my main activity:

```
// Instance variables...
private SpeechKit speechKit;
private Context context;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    context = getApplicationContext();
    ...
    this.speechKit = SpeechKit.initialize(context,
            "CORRECT_API_KEY",
            "sslsandbox.nmdp.nuancemobility.net",
            443,
            true,
            SpeechKitAPIKey);
    speechKit.connect();
}

public void invokeDialog() {
    ...
    dialogueFragment.setContext(context);
    dialogueFragment.setSpeechKit(speechKit);
    ... 
}
```

And here's my code for the dialog fragment:

```
   public void setSpeechKit(SpeechKit speechKit) {
    this.speechKit = speechKit;
}

private SpeechKit speechKit;
private Context context;

public void setSpeechKit(SpeechKit speechKit) {
    this.speechKit = speechKit;
}

public void setContext(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

// Called when a button is pushed...
public void narrateText(String voice, String phrase) {
    Vocalizer vocalizer = speechKit.createVocalizerWithVoice(voice, this, handler);
    vocalizer.speakString(phrase, context);
}
```

Now I have no idea why this error is called. The code compiles fine. Any suggestions please?

Comment: hello. did you figure out the problem as I currently have the same one ?

Comment: I wish I could say that I figured it out, but I didn't :( ... I abandoned the project since then. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, turned out to be that my free account expired (it lasts 90 days).

You probably send the login that is not valid anymore.

Comment: Thing is, I created the account merely a few days before I started writing code. Maybe my account was invalid or something. Anyways, I stopped working on that project. Thanks for your help.